# Strange logout issue in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

To prevent caching in codeigniter, I am using

```
<?php
header('Expires: Sun, 01 Jan 1995 00:00:00 GMT');
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');    
header('Pragma: no-cache');
?>
```

In logout I unset the session data and destroy the session

```
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    $this->session->unset_userdata('name');
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('user/login');
```

When I press backbutton first time, only the login page comes up and not the other visited pages. So I assumed that no-cache is working.

But if I keep pressing the back button then confirm form re-submission page comes up and when i refresh the page, the home page shows up. The session data "name" is used for displaying user name and it displays as blank.

I use the below code on all controller functions to prevent access

```
if(!$this->user->is_logged_in()) {
        redirect('user/login');
    }
```

The definition is in the model

```
public function is_logged_in()
{
    return $this->session->userdata('logged_in') ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Please guide me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> > Each and every controller check SESSION is set TRUE. If TRUE continue your code to else redirect to login page.

**In Controller**

```
public function index()
{

    $logged = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
    if($logged == TRUE)
    {
        # Your code 
    }
    else{
        # redirect login page
        redirect('login');

    }
}
```

**In Login Function**

```
$newdata = array(
    'username'  => $value,
    'logged_in' => TRUE
);

$this->session->set_userdata($newdata);
```

And destroying sesstion set like this.

```
$this->load->driver('cache');
$this->session->sess_destroy();
$this->cache->clean();
redirect('login');
ob_clean();
```

Comment: I have done this but the problem remains. This problem is not seen in firefox but both in chrome and IE. After logging out and pressing the back button, when I refresh the page the home page shows up. But the session data "name" is displayed as blank.

Comment: I have solved it. The issue was with the login controller where after successful authentication, i loaded the page view. Now instead of loading the page in login controller, i redirected to another controller where after checking is_logged_in, i load the page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue in a project but this thing helped me. I changed my config/config.php file on line where it say

$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

I Changed to TRUE and it solved my issue.